# Sql injection from brakeman for Order by field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails version: 5.1.7

Getting Brakeman vulnerability warning for order by field with where clause query in rails
Can, anyone help me to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Query for your reference:

```
DropdownValue.where(:dropdown_id => PreferenceValue.find(params[:id]).preference.dropdown_id).order("field(id, #{PreferenceValue.find(params[:id]).dropdown_value_ids.join(",")})")
```

Comment: can you share the issue as you see it in terminal

Answer (score 1):

With ActiveRecord sanitize_sql_for_order, i fixed the brakeman sql injection warning

DropdownValue.where(dropdown_id: @preference_value.preference.dropdown_id).order(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_for_order, "field(id, #{@preference_value.dropdown_value_ids.join(',')})" ))

Answer (score 1):

I was getting that when using `.order("field(id, ...)`

## Problem

I was trying this inside a model:

```
scope :order_by_type, lambda {
    order_rule = %w[B A C]
    order("my_field, #{order_rule}")
}
```

Then I was getting:

```
ActiveSupport::DeprecationException: DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "FIELD(my_field, 'B','A','C')"
```

## Solution

I ended up using this neat gem https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified

It got as simple as

```
MyModel.order_as_specified(my_field: order_rule)
```

Comment: Thanks for the gem! It's a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of this line

```
"#{PreferenceValue.find(params[:id]).dropdown_value_ids.join(",")}"
```

do this,

```
dropdown_ids = PreferenceValue.find(params[:id]).dropdown_value_ids.join(",")
```

and then in main query

```
"field(id, #{PreferenceValue.connection.quote(dropdown_ids)})"
```

`connection.quote` whitelists the interpolated values.

Give it a try.

Comment: Getting "undefined local variable or method `connection' for main:Object" error for connection.quote

Answer (score 0):

While not quite a SQL injection vulnerability this whole query is an absolute mess and something that probably should be solved via joining or indirect associations.

You can fix the breakman warning by using a bound parameter instead:

```
.order("field(id, ?)", PreferenceValue.find(params[:id]).dropdown_value_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first answer,
there is no prepared statement in .order() method and this is not a solution.

For my case this one was the working solution:

```rb
@skus = skus_scope.preload(...).order(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_for_order, "field(id, #{sku_ids.join(',')})"))
```

You could also go for something cleaner like:

```rb
@skus = skus_scope.preload(...).order(sanitize_sql_for_order(["field(id, ?)", sku_ids]))
```